# I know that string.format will box certain object, does the same hold true when just concatenation string?

Tags: c#, .net, boxing

I was reading up on boxing and `string.format()`.  And I learned that it will box a value type, such as an integer.

So the following code will cause boxing

```
var number = 5;
var sampleString = string.Format("The number 5: {0}", number);
```

This code will result in the string

```
The number 5: 5
```

However, if I concatenate using the standard `+` operator, it still produces the same string.

```
var sampleString = "The number 5: " + number;
```

What's going on here, is this also converting the integer to an object as well?

This also works with a date object, such as

```
var dateString = string.Format("The date: {0}", DateTime.Now);
var dateString = "The date: " + DateTime.Now;
```

I imagine the first line will box, but won't the second line as well?

Comment: Yes, that's converted to a String.Concat() call which needs .ToString() which needs an object.

Comment: and here is a nice article explaining / showing it: http://jeffbarnes.net/blog/post/2006/08/08/Avoid-Boxing-When-Using-StringFormat-with-Value-Types.aspx

Comment: That article is what started me on this path.  But it's specifically about string.format, what I want to know is if the same rules apply to the standard operator.  The difference being that `string.format` isn't expecting string, it's expecting objects, but `+` is expecting strings.

Comment: @CarstenKönig: In the article, the boxing is avoided by calling ToString, which is not called here.

Comment: Binary `+`: *any non-string argument is converted to its string representation by invoking the virtual ToString method inherited from type object*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For: `var dateString = "The date: " + DateTime.Now;`

`+` will be converted to `String.Concat` call, and in your code it will call [`string.Concat(object,object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbseaaft(v=vs.110).aspx) overload. This will cause the the boxing of value type `DateTime.Now` to object.

Have a look at the IL generated.

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       55 (0x37)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] string dateString0,
           [1] string dateString1)
  IL_0000:  ldstr      "The date: {0}"
  IL_0005:  call       valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime [mscorlib]System.DateTime::get_Now()
  IL_000a:  box        [mscorlib]System.DateTime
  IL_000f:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Format(string,
                                                              object)
  IL_0014:  stloc.0
  IL_0015:  ldstr      "The date: "
  IL_001a:  call       valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime [mscorlib]System.DateTime::get_Now()
  IL_001f:  box        [mscorlib]System.DateTime
  IL_0024:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(object,
                                                              object)
  IL_0029:  stloc.1
  IL_002a:  ldloc.0
  IL_002b:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_0030:  ldloc.1
  IL_0031:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_0036:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

As you can see in the IL the string concatenation translates into call to

```
  IL_0024:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(object,
                                                              object)
```

And here is the code for generated IL

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var dateString0 = string.Format("The date: {0}", DateTime.Now);
    var dateString1 = "The date: " + DateTime.Now;
    Console.WriteLine(dateString0);
    Console.WriteLine(dateString1);
}
```

In case of `String.Format` boxing will take place as well.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  The call to string.Concat takes in two objects which is what string.format does.  That's where I was lost.  I was trying to read up on the operator and I didn't find anything that points to string.Concat.

Comment: I assume this applies to any value type. Such as an integer.

Comment: Thank you very much for going the extra mile and posting the genarate IL.  I'll accept this answer when the wait period is over.